# How to use firebase remove() callback method in react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-redux

i am using firebase for database and i have two  collections taskData and archiveData,
i want to remove one fild form taskData and add to archiveData i have also use redux in project

```
export const addToArchive = (key, categoryKey) => {
  return async dispatch => {
    database()
      .ref('/todoDatabase/' + categoryKey + '/data/' + key)
      .remove();
      dispatch({
        type: ActionTypes.ADD_TO_ARCHIVE,
      });
  };
};
```

basically i want when data is removed from taskData then add new fild to archiveData so how can i use callback method for '.remove()'